# Utilizar variable en State en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
class Segunda extends StatefulWidget {

  int id;
  Segunda({Key key, this.id,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SegundaState createState() => _SegundaState();
}

class _SegundaState extends State<Segunda> {
  get id => widget.id;
  id++;
.....
}
```

La variable "id" viene de una 'pantalla' previa (Primera).  Y requiero poderla utilizar en distintos métodos de la _SegundaState, pero todos los ensayos han sido infructuosos.  Ni siquiera ejecuta la instrucción "id++" del código, ya que efectivamente se recibe la variable como de tipo int según lo indicado.

¿Qué hace falta? ¿Dónde está el error?  Agradezco su colaboración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usarla en el `State` sin ningún problemas, si es que estás pasando el valor correctamente, puedes declarar una variable local en el `State` para que puedas asignarle el valor que viene del widget, dentro del método `initState`, y luego puedes realizar las operaciones que quieras, prueba mostrando la info en un `Widget` así :

```dart
class _SegundaState extends State<Segunda> {

  int _myID;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _myID = widget.id;
    _myID++;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(Object context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(_myID.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @diegodeveloper gracias, muy aclarador.  Sin embargo, me surge una duda: además de ésta variable de tipo int, y que no podía manipular, tengo otra de tipo String que he posido pasar de una 'pantalla' a otra.  ¿Por qué este caso no, y el otro sí?

Comment: El problema surge cuando quiero por ejemplo actualizar el valor de la variable, caso en el cual es necesario utilizar una NUEVA (myID en tu ejemplo), ya que la original (id) no sirve.  ¿Por qué es necesario hacer esto?  Es por ahí mi duda, que supongo es conceptual.  Gracias!

Comment: Como dices, es conceptual, los widgets son inmutables, es decir que no deberias actualizar los parametros que se pasan a widgets, pero sí puedes hacerlo con las variables declaradas dentro del State/Estado, es por eso, además lo correcto es que declares como final, el atributo id del widget. final int id;

Comment: Gracias Diego @diegodeveloper, y listos tus likes!